# D3 curved link with arrow not appearing on screen

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add the curved links with the arrow as per this [d3noob's block](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5141278) to my [codepen](https://codepen.io/aa1024/pen/mjPaBQ?editors=1010).

After adding 2 nodes (`Add Node` button) and selecting the source node and target node from the select boxes when I press the `Add Link` button it does not show the link, however, the nodes readjust on the screen giving an idea that a link has been created.

I added the following code (including some variable definitions in codepen)

```
path.attr("d", function(d) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return "M" + 
        d.source.x + "," + 
        d.source.y + "A" + 
        dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + 
        d.target.x + "," + 
        d.target.y;
});
```

it was earlier :

```
link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x;    })
.attr("y1", function(d) {   return d.source.y;    })
.attr("x2", function(d) {   return d.target.x;    })
.attr("y2", function(d) {   return d.target.y;    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you haven't actually created any  objects to change the attributes of, you tried to create the paths off of the force links at the top of your file, before any links had actually been created. You needed to create the paths based on the links in your 'restart' function and then update their attributes in the 'tick' function. Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RBazVp?editors=0010

Here's the relevant changes:

```
function restart() {
       ...
       ...
  link = link.data(links);
  link.enter()
      .append('path')
      .attr('class', 'link');
  link.exit().remove();

  force.start();
       ...
       ...
}

function tick() {
  link.attr("d", function(d) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return (
      "M" +
      d.source.x +
      "," +
      d.source.y +
      "A" +
      dr +
      "," +
      dr +
      " 0 0,1 " +
      d.target.x +
      "," +
      d.target.y
    );
  });
       ...
       ...
}
```

To add arrows to the links:

```
var arrows = svg.append("defs")
            .selectAll("marker")
              .data(["arrow"])
              .enter()
              .append("marker")
                .attr("id", String)
                .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
                .attr("refX", 15)
                .attr("refY", -1.5)
                .attr("markerWidth", 6)
                .attr("markerHeight", 6)
                .attr("orient", "auto")
                .append("path")
                  .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

function restart() {
       ...
       ...
  link = link.data(links);
  link.enter()
      .append('path')
      .attr('class', 'link')
      .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrow)');  
  link.exit().remove();

  force.start();
       ...
       ...
}
```

Interestingly, you only need to define and create the arrow once, and changing the 'marker-end' attribute will automatically generate another copy of the arrow. Pretty neat!

Comment: Thanks @REEE;  is it possible to add an arrowhead to the links in the same code?

Comment: No problem, yeah you should be able to, I'll take a look now. I may be 20-30 minutes though as I'm in work.

Comment: @nyi Just added the code for arrows in the codepen and the answer above. Hope that helps. It's looking a lot nicer now btw, the images on the nodes are a nice touch!

Comment: Thanks a ton @REEE. My aim is to connect the html page to a WebSocket sending add/delete node/link information, currently, I am trying to simulate it via html/javascript functions.